# Как сделать анимацию движения кнопки по нажатии на нее?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qpushbutton, qpropertyanimation

Хочу сделать плавное передвижение кнопки по нажатии на нее. 
Как это сделать?

Код:

```
...

def MouseMenu():
    ui.MouseClicker.move(20, 20)

    ...    

ui.MouseClicker.clicked.connect(lambda: MouseMenu())
...
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: В Моем Случае Это Не Возможно, Пишу Интерфейс На Qt Designer, Фунцианал На Питоне В PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, я не просил вас предоставить проект, 
я попросил предоставить **`минимально-воспроизводимый пример`**.

Класс `QPropertyAnimation` анимирует свойства *Qt*.

То, что вы хотите сделать, называется анимацией и
выглядит это примерно так:

```
import sys
from random import randrange
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mouseClicker = QPushButton('Click \nme', self)
        self.mouseClicker.setGeometry(350, 200, 96, 96)
        self.mouseClicker.clicked.connect(self.mouse_menu) 
        
        self.pos_x1 = self.mouseClicker.pos().x()
        self.pos_y1 = self.mouseClicker.pos().y()
        self.w, self.h = ..., ...

    def new_pos(self):
        self.pos_x1 = self.mouseClicker.pos().x()
        self.pos_y1 = self.mouseClicker.pos().y()
        
    def mouse_menu(self):
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.mouseClicker, b"geometry")
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)
        self.pos_x2 = randrange(1, self.w-100)
        self.pos_y2 = randrange(1, self.h-100)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QRect(self.pos_x1, self.pos_y1, 96, 96))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QRect(self.pos_x2, self.pos_y2, 96, 96))
        self.animation.start()
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.new_pos)        
 
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.w, self.h = self.size().width(), self.size().height() 


QSS = '''
QPushButton {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    min-width:  96px;
    max-width:  96px;
    min-height: 96px;
    max-height: 96px;
    border-radius: 48px;        /* круглый */
}
'''
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(800, 500)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @CoCuCka что не так?